# Android Array List

Tags: android, arraylist

I am getting an error on this line:-"`for(Item item:Items)`" on "`Items`" keyword and the error is "`Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to Item`". somebody Please  help me out for this.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Model 
{
    public static ArrayList Items;

    public static void LoadModel()
    {
        Items=new ArrayList();
        Items.add(new Item(1, "taj.png", "Taj Mahal", "arrow.png"));
        Items.add(new Item(2, "agra_fort.png", "Agra Fort", "arrow.png"));
        Items.add(new Item(3, "chini _ka_rauza.png", "Chini ka Rauza", "arrow.png"));
        Items.add(new Item(4, "fatepur_sikri.png", "Fatepur Sikri", "arrow.png"));
        Items.add(new Item(5, "guru_ka_tal.png", "Guru Ka Tal", "arrow.png"));
        Items.add(new Item(6, "jamma_masjid.png", "Jamma Masjid", "arrow.png"));
        Items.add(new Item(7, "mankameshwar_temple.png", "Mankameshwar", "arrow.png"));
        Items.add(new Item(8, "mehtab_baug.png", "Mehtab Baug", "arrow.png"));
        Items.add(new Item(9, "musamman_burj.png", "Musamman Burj", "arrow.png"));
        Items.add(new Item(10, "panch_mahal.png", "Panch Mahal", "arrow.png"));


    }
    public static Item GetbyId(int id)
    {
        for(Item item:Items)
        {
            if(item.id==id)
            {
                return item;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Try to declare list this way : public static ArrayList<Item> Items;

Comment: Hey thnx..the error is solved but my project isnt working..i am getting force close.

Comment: Try to print both item.id and id value before compare it.

Comment: Why are you create custom holder class from item you can simply hold this type data using HashMap if you prefer.

Comment: Sorry but i dint get you..can you explain little more.

Comment: can you send me your project then i try to optimize your code ?

Comment: Should i post d complete code

Comment: ya sure...should i post here or mail it to you

Comment: I have mailed it please check out and help me for it.thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please let me know about assert images ?

Comment: ...why is everything static?

Comment: which assert images are you talking about

Comment: Please check your mail.

Comment: @haresh-Thank you very much for the code.Its working perfectly.Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

First initialize the ArrayList as

```
  ArrayList<Item> Items = new ArrayList<Item>();
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be `Items= new ArrayList<Item>();`  Otherwise Java assumes the worst case of Object.

Comment: Hey thnx..but its not working..can you suggest me something more..?

Comment: Oh, as @Aniruddha mentioned-  you need the <Item> in the declaration as well.